# How to use BigBirdModel to create a neural network in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, nlp, bert-language-model

I am trying to create a network with tenserflow and BigBird.

```
from transformers import BigBirdModel
import tensorflow as tf

classic_model = BigBirdModel.from_pretrained('google/bigbird-roberta-base')

input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(LEN, ), dtype='int64', name='input_ids')
outputs = classic_model(input_ids)
net = outputs['pooler_output']
net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=None, name='classifier')(net)
```

This is the code I used, but I get an error at this line:
`outputs = classic_model(input_ids)`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-55cb99783d63> in <module>()
      4 inputs = [input_ids, attention_ids]
      5 
----> 6 outputs = classic_model(inputs)
      7 
      8 net = outputs['pooler_output']

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/big_bird/modeling_big_bird.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   2009             raise ValueError("You cannot specify both input_ids and inputs_embeds at the same time")
   2010         elif input_ids is not None:
-> 2011             input_shape = input_ids.size()
   2012             batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
   2013         elif inputs_embeds is not None:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation: https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bigbird.html#bigbirdmodel

Anyone has any idea how to fix it?

Comment: When you say "second line", do you refer to `outputs = classic_model(input_ids)`, or something else? Would you mind including the full traceback?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's the line I was referring to. I edited the question.